# Downloading from a dynamic web application

Tags: web-scraping

I need to download  csv-file from a linux server. I donot know what  is the best way to do it.
I don't have knowledge of network programming. The reason to use c++ is that my rest program is in c++. I tried [Libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/ftp-wildcard.html), but it downloads only HTML page.

I attach screenshots to make my question more clear.

Step:1 login to page
[image: STEP 1]

Step2 & 3: [image: Select download and select files, and drag and drop files to download]

Step4 &5:[image: Select dataset and click download]

My question is, how can I do it using c++. Any external library (opensource/comercial)?

Any guidelines/ link to download file automatically.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you insist on C++ even though you do not know programming? This seems like a job for a headless browser like CasperJS, PhantomJS, or Selenium.

Comment: Asking for library recommendations isn't [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: And libcurl should be plenty enough to download anything you need. Perhaps you didn't use the correct URL? Perhaps the page needs some kind of authentication? What is the contents of the "page" you do get downloaded? What does it say?

Comment: This page clearly needs JavaScript to operate, so you either drive a headless browser like I said, or you figure out the actual call made when you click "download" and emulate that with curl. Use your browser's network inspection pane to look at the request and then see if you can emulate it. (there is a "copy as cURL command" option)

Comment: @Botje This page -----(What do you mean? You mean to add JS in URL page on server side? This cannot be done. I am not owner of the website. Or you mean that I can use some script for repeated steps to get info from the website.

Comment: Steps 2,3,4,5 all involve JavaScript running in the browser, with only step 5 possibly doing an HTTP call (the thing curl does). This is why I have suggested either using a headless browser or reverse engineering the final HTTP call.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a file in C++ is very simple. As long as curl is installed in your system, you shouldn't need anything outside of what your compiler already provides.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // curl                         - app that will do the downloading
    // https://url.com/what/ever/   - url of the file
    // >                            - tells computer to redirect output into a file
    // file.txt                     - the file that will store the output
    
    // 1.) --- Construct your command ---
    string str = R"dil(curl https://url.com/what/ever/ > file.txt)dil";

    // 2.) --- Print command to screen (optional) ---
    cout << str << endl;

    // 3.) --- Execute command ---
    system(str.c_str());

    cout << "Press any key...";
    cin.get();    // pause till user presses a key
    return 0;
}
```

Your file will be created in the directory the program was run from.
When compiling form an IDE, this is usually the directory of your source code.